# Want to show loader GIF in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables. My code is working fine. Now I want to add a loader image (gif). I don't know how to add this. Here is my datatable script so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dvloader").show();
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"                   
    });
});
```

Here is my loader:

```
<div id="loader">
    <img src="ajaxloader.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: you didnt mention where and on which event you want to display this image,Do you want to replace the 'Processing,,,' string with this image?

Comment: @anu yes I want to display image.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you want to replace the 'Processing...' string with an image as you mentioned in the comment you need to take a look [here](http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=2250&page=1)

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    oLanguage: {
        sProcessing: "<img src='loading.gif'>"
    },
    processing : true
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add option `processing: true`

Comment: For anyone stuck using legacy datatables you need to use `bProcessing: true` instead of `processing: true`

Comment: I have used the same manner, but image is not showing for IE 11 and Chrome. It's only working fine in Firfox.

Comment: The Hyperlink is broken.

Comment: The new link is here ! https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Answer (score 13):

In datatables 1.10 and onwards, you should use:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  language: {
     processing: "<img src='loading.gif'>"
  },
  processing: true
});
```

Not required as of today, but more standard given the new documentation. The project changed from using [Hungarian notation to standard camelCase](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-naming) in the most recent update. Of interest:

> Please note that the Hungarian notation option is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of the extensions (on the extension's next major version update - i.e. 1.x to 2.x, although 2.x is not planned for a long time to come - plenty of life in the 1.x series still!). The documentation for the extensions will be updated to remove the Hungarian notation before that point.