# How can I retain a copy of data before binding jQuery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/), and I have an ajax data source. However, what I'd like to do is:

1. Initialize the datatable (empty), but have the 'loading' banner on it. I can initialize the datatable just fine, but it won't continue to show the loading banner regardless of `processing: true` because it's finished processing the empty data set.
2. Begin my own independent ajax ($.getJSON) request for the data, storing the json response in a javascript variable, which could be a short delay.
3. Once the ajax request returns, then populate the data into the datatable and clear the 'loading' banner (I'm not clear on how to 'set' the data source of a DataTable post-initialization)
4. Use the data to also create a graph (likely with D3.js), this will be with the javascript object from the ajax call in #2.

I can't find a way to initialize the datatable into a 'loading' state, or to populate it once the data is loaded. I want to avoid two separate ajax requests (once for the datatable, another for the graph).

Is this possible?

```
//Pseudo-code
var myData = [];

var dt = $("#table").dataTables({
  processing = true //?? Loading does not remain while ajax request below executes
});

$.getJSON("/api/data", function (data) {
    myData = data;
    dt.bind(myData); //?? Don't know how to do this
    dt.processing = false; //?? Turn off loading message
  }
});
```

Comment: Create your own pre Loader Function ,that toggles state between on and off

Comment: How do I initialize it with the loading 'stuck', and how do I then bind it after initialization to my object?

Comment: Post your current code snippet...else the question is off topic you are asking for opinion based answers.

Comment: Initialise the DataTable on an empty HTML table. Then do your ajax call in an `fnInitComplete` function. Do whatever you want with the data returned (including adding it to the table and drawing a chart). Bob's your Uncle etc...

Comment: I added the best I can do. If I knew how to write it, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: for showing image when loading data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648643/want-to-show-loader-gif-in-datatables#answer-5649277

Comment: How do I add the data to the table once it's returned?

Comment: You mean you want to reload data after certain event.check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049439/how-to-set-dynamically-the-ajax-url-of-a-datatable/32049573#32049573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Loading" state is default. Just remove `processing : true`. I have the feeling you here are trying to use a sledgehammer for cracking a nut. To reuse the JSON and prevent multiple AJAX requests, simply use the `dataSrc` callback :

```
function d3Graph(json) {
   //initialise the d3 graph here
}
$('#example').DataTable( {
   ajax: {
      url: "/api/data",
      dataSrc: function(json) {
          d3Graph(json);
          return json;
      }     
   },
   ...
})
```

see example here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7z6aamna/**

Generally there is 3 ways to populate a dataTable with new data after it is initialised :

1. destroy and reinitialise with new options (i.e a new `data` variable)
2. use `table.ajax.reload()`
3. empty the table and insert new rows one by one programmatically

But you do not need anything like that. Your concern is only the reuse of AJAX'ed data.

---

Here is a skeleton for what you want to accomplish. Basically it is #1 of the above mentioned methods. Simply assign a `null` value to dataTables `data`, then load the JSON and after that reinitialise the dataTable (and the d3 graph or whatever). The main "trick" here is to set the language option `emptyTable` to show "*loading data ..*" instead of "*No data available in table*". I have wrapped it into a little javascript literal just to make some code out of it :

```js
var Data = {
    data : null,
    init : function() {
       this.initTable();
       this.loadData();
    },
    loadData : function() {
       $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1miqx', function(json) {
           Data.data = json;
           Data.initTable();
           Data.initGraph();
       })
    },
    initTable : function() {
       $("#example").DataTable({
          destroy : true, //important
          data : Data.data,
          language : {    //important
             emptyTable: 'Loading data ...'
          },
          columns: [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
          ]
       })
    },
    initGraph : function() {
       console.log('initialising d3 graph')
    }
}

Data.init();
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/ncLn6Lh6/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying to load my data independently of the datatable itself - I want it to sit in a 'Processing' state until I manually feed in my own data. It sounds like I might just want to just not initialize the datatable until I have the data, and just use static html for the 'processing' section, I just liked how the headers and styling looks when it's initialized and wanted it to wait like that. Are there no options to do something like `table.clear(); table.load(myDataObject);`?

Comment: @Ehryk, OK - dont know if it is any worth - perhaps you have already solved the problem yourself - but see updated answer.  It is a simple skeleton for what you are trying to accomplish, primarily showing how to reinitialise a dataTable and change default messages.